# Are there runtime defined claims for Microsoft Azure AD Verifiable Credentials

Tags: azure-ad-verifiable-credentials

In the initial preview version (Apr 2021), the documentation provides for claims to be populated from

- An ID token
- Another verifiable credential
- A self attested value
- A static value

Is there a mechanism to define a claim value at credential issuance time i.e. runtime from memory? Some claims may come from other systems or be a derived new claim from one of the values supplied above.

e.g. from the ID token I take given and family name but then from the payroll system I need to add a claim for "employee start date".

**The question**

Is there a mechanism, currently, to define a claim value at credential issuance time i.e. runtime from memory?

Answer (score 1):

Great question! At the moment this functionality is not documented but we have new feature coming soon where you can do what you are describing.